# extra point in convex hull (using graham scan) error + java

Tags: java, convex, grahams-scan

my code which is using graham algorithm to find the convex hull works pretty well (it shows me the polygon it suppose to show) but I can see that it sends me one extra collinear point  (though I'm handling the collinear point in my code)
here is my code :

```
    public Collection<Coord> territoire()
    {
        double checkPoints;
        Collection<Coord> sommets = new ArrayList<Coord>(this);
        Stack<Coord> stackOfConvexHull = new Stack<Coord>();
        ArrayList<Coord> thisToArrList = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        for(Coord c : this)
            thisToArrList.add(c);


        //sorting the array by Y
        ArrayList<Coord> sortedPointsByY = sortedArrayByY(thisToArrList); 

        //sorting the set of points with increasing order of angle
        // they and the base point (basePoint) make with X axis 
        List<Coord> sortedPointsByAngle = new ArrayList<Coord>(sortPointsByAngle(sortedPointsByY));

        if(sortedPointsByAngle.size() < 3)
            System.out.println("the convex hull of less than 3 points is not possible");
        if(collinear(sortedPointsByAngle)) 
            System.out.println("can't make a convex hull of collinear points");


        stackOfConvexHull.push(sortedPointsByAngle.get(0));
        stackOfConvexHull.push(sortedPointsByAngle.get(1));

            for (int i = 2; i < sortedPointsByAngle.size(); i++) 
            {

                Coord p1 = sortedPointsByAngle.get(i);
                Coord p2 = stackOfConvexHull.pop();
                Coord p3 = stackOfConvexHull.peek();

                checkPoints = ccw(p3, p2, p1);

                // counter-clockwise
                if(checkPoints > 0) 
                {
                    stackOfConvexHull.push(p2);
                    stackOfConvexHull.push(p1);
                }

                // collinear
                if(checkPoints == 0)
                    stackOfConvexHull.push(p1);

                // clockwise
                else
                    i--;
            }

            // end of the hull
            stackOfConvexHull.push(sortedPointsByAngle.get(0));
            sommets = new ArrayList<Coord>(stackOfConvexHull);

        return sommets;

    }

//**********************************Auxiliary méthods****************************************************

                            //***** sorting points by Y and angles *****

    //sorting the points by their y in ascending order
    public ArrayList<Coord> sortedArrayByY(ArrayList<Coord> arrayOfPoints)
    {
        Coord temp = null;
        for(int i = 0; i< arrayOfPoints.size(); i++)
        { 
            for(int j = 0; j< arrayOfPoints.size()-1; j++)
            {
                if(arrayOfPoints.get(j+1).y < arrayOfPoints.get(j).y)
                {
                    temp = arrayOfPoints.get(j+1);
                    arrayOfPoints.set(j+1, arrayOfPoints.get(j));
                    arrayOfPoints.set(j, temp);  
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayOfPoints;
    }


    public Set<Coord> sortPointsByAngle(ArrayList<Coord> points) 
    {
        int min = minYIndex(points);
        final Coord basePoint = points.get(min);

        TreeSet<Coord> set = new TreeSet<Coord>(new Comparator<Coord>() 
        {
            public int compare(Coord a, Coord b) {

                if(a == b || a.equals(b))
                    return 0;

               double firstAngle = angle(basePoint, a);
               double secondAngle = angle(basePoint, b);

                if(firstAngle < secondAngle) 
                    return -1;

                else if(firstAngle > secondAngle) 
                    return 1;

                else 
                {
                    // collinear with the 'basePoint' point, let the point closest to it come first
                    double firstDistance = findDistance(basePoint, a);
                    double secondDistance = findDistance(basePoint, b);

                    if(firstDistance < secondDistance) 
                        return -1;    

                    else 
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        });

        set.addAll(points);
        return set;
    }


    // find the buttom most point (minimum Y)
    // if If the lowest y-coordinate exists in 
    // more than one point in the set, the point with the one with the lowest x-coordinate 
    // will be chosen

    public int minYIndex(ArrayList<Coord> sortedPointsByY)
    {   
        int min = 0;
        for ( int i = 1; i < sortedPointsByY.size(); i++ ) // O(n) => n number of points
        {
            if ( sortedPointsByY.get(i).y == sortedPointsByY.get(min).y) 
            {
                if ( sortedPointsByY.get(i).x < sortedPointsByY.get(min).x)
                    min = i;
            }
            else if ( sortedPointsByY.get(i).y < sortedPointsByY.get(min).y)
                min = i;
        }
        return min;
    }

    public double angle(Coord basePoint, Coord a) 
    {
        return Math.atan2(a.y - basePoint.y, a.x - basePoint.x);
    }


    public double findDistance(Coord basePoint, Coord a)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(((basePoint.x - a.x) * (basePoint.x - a.x)) + 
                ((basePoint.y - a.y) * (basePoint.y - a.y)));
    }


    //if the result is zero, the point is collinear 
    //if it is positive, the three points constitute left turn (counter clockwise)
    //else the three points constitute right turn (clockwise)    
    public double ccw(Coord p1, Coord p2, Coord p3)
    {
        return (p2.x - p1.x)*(p3.y - p1.y) - (p2.y - p1.y)*(p3.x - p1.x);
    }

 // check if the points are collinear   
    public boolean collinear(List<Coord> sortedPointsByAngle) 
    {

        Coord a, b, c;
        if(sortedPointsByAngle.size() < 2) 
            return true;

        a = sortedPointsByAngle.get(0);
        b = sortedPointsByAngle.get(1);

        for(int i = 2; i < sortedPointsByAngle.size(); i++) 
        {

            c = sortedPointsByAngle.get(i);

            if(ccw(a, b, c) != 0) 
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I'm so waiting to have some hints to help me find my problem

Comment: a picture would be nice here

Comment: how can I put the image in this site?

Comment: Can you provide your input example? That way it's easier to spot the problem.

Comment: that's my input: 0 0
0 3.75
1 2.5
1 0.5
1.5 1.5
-4 1.5
-3 1.3
-2 1.1
-1 0.9
0 0.7
-2.9 1.5
-1.8 1.5
-0.7 1.5
0.6 1.5
-3 1.7
-2 1.9
-1 2.1
0 2.3
-3.2 1.2
-2.4 0.9
-1.6 0.6
-0.8 0.3
-3.2 1.95
-2.4 2.4
-1.6 2.85
-0.8 3.3

and this is my output: 

0.0 0.0
1.0 0.5
1.5 1.5
1.0 2.5
0.0 3.75
-1.6 2.85
-4.0 1.5
0.0 0.0

Comment: wow, that's quite huge, I was hoping for a square or so ;) can you find a smaller example with the same issue?

Comment: I don't know but if you could send me your email, so that I could show u the image that would be better ...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a rounding problem. You compute this expression (function `ccw`)

```
(p2.x - p1.x)*(p3.y - p1.y) - (p2.y - p1.y)*(p3.x - p1.x)
```

with double precision. The chances that it will be *exactly* `0` are small.

What I usually do to solve this (though it's not a very clean practice) is to just test for 'almost 0':

```
if (Math.abs(checkPoints) < 0.0000001) // colinear
```

Comment: you mean I put this condition inside my ccw function?

Comment: @NavidKoochooloo no, I meant after the call (in `territoire`), instead of `if(checkPoints == 0)`